# Getting JSON format of a node using drupal

Tags: 8

I am having issues receiving JSON data of a node with Drupal 8 Core REST. Here are the steps I have went through several times:

1. Install latest version of drupal 8
2. Enable all core web services modules (HAL, HTTP Basic Authentication, RESTful Web Services, Serialization)
3. Go to permissions page. Find RESTful Web Services permissions and allow delete, get, patch, and post for all users.

I created a path using Views module to show JSON format of my website contents and it works fine:
http://www.example.com/api/v1/order/

but when I use the following URL to Get the JSON format of a node using `POSTMAN` or `DHC client`, it returns HTML format of data!:

http://www.example.com/node/1?_format=json

Comment: Did you enable the `json` format in node endpoint at `/admin/config/services/rest`?

Comment: Yes, I enabled josn, hal+json and xml format using REST UI module.

Comment: Well, in latest release there is no permission for REST API endpoints. May be you wanna try the latest release.

Comment: I ran into a similar problem. If it helps anyone who finds this later, the core doc suggestion of using curl http://example.com/node/1?_format=hal_json (seen here: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/core/modules/rest/2-get-for-reading-content-entities) doesn't work. If you just use your browser to go to the address though, you'll see json formatted data.