# Where are the RESTful module permissions other than `Administer REST resource configuration`?

Tags: users, 8

According to the tutorial [An Introduction to RESTful Web Services in Drupal 8](https://drupalize.me/blog/201401/introduction-restful-web-services-drupal-8), the `admin/people/permissions` path should contain the following permissions:

[image: RESTful Web Services]

But now that I installed the latest version of Drupal, the big surprise is on my website there are no other RESTful module permissions than `Administer REST resource configuration`, no permissions to grant DELETE, GET, PATCH or POST to each role.

[image]

I have Enabled all core web services modules (HAL, HTTP Basic Authentication, RESTful Web Services, Serialization) + REST UI module.

Are those permissions removed from Drupal 8.2.5?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This was introduced since 8.2.0

[Accessing entities via REST no longer requires additional REST-specific permissions](https://www.drupal.org/node/2733435)

> **This was actually only meant to be a temporary measure**, because we
>   already have an Entity Access API that governs access/operations to/on
>   those entities. And in fact, Entity Access is respected when accessing
>   entities via REST. So, there was no more reason for this to exist in
>   Drupal 8.0.x and Drupal 8.1.x, but it was simply forgotten to be
>   removed before Drupal 8.0.0's release. The fact that you needed to
>   grant both those permissions as well as Entity Access needing to grant
>   you access, was a source of confusion and frustration with Drupal 8's
>   REST API, which has now been fixed.
>
> **So, as of Drupal 8.2.0, new installations no longer need those permissions to access entities via REST**. Existing installations
>   continue to have the old behavior. Existing sites can opt out of that
>   behavior, and opt in to the new behavior, by modifying the
>   rest.settings configuration from
>
> `bc_entity_resource_permissions: true`
>
> to
>
> `bc_entity_resource_permissions: false`
>
> (The latter is the default on new Drupal 8.2 installations.)

Comment: for my case that installed drupal 8.2, in order to get the REST module to work properly, should I left the bc_entity_resource_permissions: false or change it to true?

Comment: @Mde leave it false. The previous permissions it had was only temporary. Not having them is how D8 was/is meant to be.

Comment: thanks @No Sssweat, I thought the problem of my following question was this issue: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/226130/getting-json-format-of-a-node-using-drupal , but it seems the problem is something else, could you help me solve it? thanks again.